# Can "second only to something" express the two are similar?

Tags: meaning, expressions, ielts

There was this question in [an IELTS reading passage](https://ieltstrainingonline.com/ielts-reading-recent-actual-test-01-with-answer/) (answer by true/false/not given):

> The research found that scientists can make chimpanzees possess the same complex culture as human beings.

The sentence most likely being addressed is:

> These researchers frequently quote the word ‘culture’ to describe elementary animal behaviours, like the regional dialects of different species of songbirds, but it turns out that the rich and varied cultural traditions chimpanzees enjoyed rank secondly in complexity only to human traditions.

While I assumed it was wrong given it places second to that of humans, but the correct answer is 'Not Given'. Does that mean "second only to" means it is "less that or similar"? Or am I missing something entirely different?

Comment: The sentence definitely does not state that scientists _can make_ chimpanzees have any kind of culture, complex or otherwise.

Comment: It says that the culture of chimps is more complex than that of any other species **except** human beings.

Comment: You are indeed missing 'something different'. Read the question carefully.

Comment: You can find the meaning of "second only to" in [Collins COBUILD](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/second-only-to-something)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Oh alright. Thanks  :/

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be an exercise in comprehension. The text you quoted says that:

'Researchers' **have found** that chimpanzees **have** cultural traditions that are **less complex** than those of humans.

The question text says:

The research found that **scientists can make** chimpanzees possess **the same** complex culture as human beings.

You are asked to state whether this is true or false (according to the quoted text) or 'not given'. It is not given. Nowhere does the text say that scientists can 'make' chimpanzees have a complex culture (*how could they do that?*), and the text does not say that chimps' cultural complexity is the same as humans' (it says it is less). It certainly does not say that chimps can possess the 'same culture' as human beings.